# Equivalent of Export-Csv to Write-Output

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

How can I convert an object into a series of CSV strings and output the strings to another command?

The `Export-Csv` cmdlet will only output to a file.  I want to send the CSV output to another command or script output.

As a workaround, I could use `Export-Csv` to a file, read the file, then delete the file, but that approach has too much unnecessary overhead.

> **[Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6)**
>
> Converts objects into a series of comma-separated value (CSV) strings
>   and saves the strings to a file.

Comment: Use the `ConvertTo-CSV` cmdlet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Export-csv** is a combination of **ConvertTo-CSV** piped to **Out-file**:

Ex:

```
Get-Process | Select-Object -property Name,ID,VM,PM | ConvertTo-CSV | Out-File test2.html
```

you can use:

```
$a = Get-Process | Select-Object -property Name,ID,VM,PM | ConvertTo-CSV
```

Comment: Except export-csv defaults to ascii encoding, and out-file defaults to unicode encoding.

Answer (score 9):

You should use the [ConvertTo-CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv?view=powershell-6) cmdlet if you want to convert objects to CSV and return the result to stdout, instead of a file.

> The ConvertTo-CSV cmdlet returns a series of comma-separated value (CSV) strings that represent the objects that you submit. You can then use the ConvertFrom-Csv cmdlet to recreate objects from the CSV strings. The objects converted from CSV are string values of the original objects that contain property values and no methods.

You'll find most builtin `Export-` cmdlets have a `ConvertTo-` equivalent. Another good way to discover cmdlets is to use `Get-Command` with a wildcard:

```
~> Get-Command *csv

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           epcsv -> Export-Csv
Alias           ipcsv -> Import-Csv
Cmdlet          ConvertFrom-Csv                                    3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
Cmdlet          ConvertTo-Csv                                      3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
Cmdlet          Export-Csv                                         3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
Cmdlet          Import-Csv                                         3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility
```